# Missing parameter: `type`

Tags: coinbase-api

anyone has idea why coinbase api respond
`{'errors': [{'id': 'invalid_request', 'message': 'Missing parameter:`type`'}]}`

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/account_number/transactions
with params 
`tx = {
    'type': 'request',
    'to': 'user@example.com',
    'amount': '0.001',
    'currency': 'BTC',
 }`

and works fine if Im going to send
`tx = {
    'type': 'send',
    'to': 'user@example.com',
    'amount': '0.001',
    'currency': 'BTC',
 }`

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve it?

Comment: nope, thats coinbase API bug, it were there for ages now :(

Comment: Still facing the same problem. Did you find a fix?

Comment: This appears to be a known issue on coinbase here: https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-ios-sdk/issues/54